# Is there event-based web framework for Java similar to Android API?

Tags: java, android, web-applications

As stated in the question, I am looking for a Java-based (hopefully that does not require a full application server) event-based web applications development framework.

I have tried Vaadin, it was driving me insane. ZK Framework seems interesting, but it is pretty complex and there are no good examples of complex MVVC applications I know of, even though MVVC is the "way to go" in this framework.

Preferably, the framework I am looking for would be as much as possible similar to Android API, in the sense that the API is really well designed and that one can build very complex applications with it (i.e. CRUD interface within a CRUD, within a CRUD, with everything working as expected).

Another thing which we need is that the framework can be used not just for building business application, but also that web frontend can be built on top of it (even if special controls/widgets are needed).

Any ideas?

Comment: The "type" of application (business vs. anything else) is hardly framework-dependent. As far as things being "complex" -- a framework that allows for complexity will be complex. Without knowing what about Vaadin "drove you insane" it's difficult to know what *won't* "drive you insane". The canonical component framework for Java web apps is JSF.

Comment: Re Vaadin, I have given it a real try, even a few times. For starters things like lists/items are hopelessly too complex, so you have to override toString() and hashCode(), which breaks other things for me (I already have a standard-architectured JEE application, and was trying to replace the UI). Also I am using a full JEE app server, and JPA support was very poor in Vaadin with many problems.  Or you have to buy their component to use it. With Vaadin I found myself writing really 10x more code than in Struts2 or PHP ZK1.

Comment: If you're *just* trying to replace the UI, IMO I'd use a client-side framework and consume services. Which one depends on what you're most comfortable with. I don't understand why you're saying you have a complete JEE app and you want to replace just the UI but you want it Java-based--Java web app front-ends aren't written in Java unless you use GWT or something on top of it.

Comment: I actually meant that we have EJB modules and JEE webapps (in Struts) and I was exploring alternative framework. I was using "frontend" term in a bit broader sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try GWT. Google Web toolkit is powerful tool for creating rich web application using Java as development language and eclipse as IDE. GWT provide cross browser ability and boilerplate code, so it is easy to bring rich AJAX based widgets. GWT is nice when you really need rich behavior capabilities on your client (GMail-like application).

It works very well with CRUD operation.

Comment: The problem with GWT is that you basically have to write your own theme, the default one is sh*t. Also, I think there is a reason why Vaadin exists, i.e. it extends GWT, which is something I would expect is already present in the base framework. GWT looks to me like something where HTML/CSS/JS is not obscured enough, and honestly I am trying to run away from HTML/CSS.

Comment: I am just writing this to eat my own words. I have took a brief look at GWT in the past and have left it alone unsatisfied, because for example it does not play well for a customer-facing website (because of SEO problems since everything is basically generated JavaScript). But I guess the option is to use GWT for backend/admin part of the application and use some other, more SEO-friendly framework, for customer-facing web (any suggestions?). SmartGWT also takes care of my "ugly default template" comment, so I am accepting your answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to avoid "server-side only" frameworks you may have also a look at Apache Wicket as an alternative to JSF

Comment: Wicket is primarily a server-side technology :P

Comment: @arun true, i just wanted to propse an alternative to the vaadim/zk/gwt league

Comment: Sorry but Wicket is not even worth considering. Just a few widgets, poor documentation, no real examples. Just what I need. This looks like a framework for hackers, and I really want something where I can just write apps more productively than with PHP Zend Framework v1, not something where I have to Google whole day to solve the basic tasks 95% people need in any framework. But thank you for the suggestion.